# Chaining multiple .map calls together, more efficient way to query data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I find myself sometimes needing to "find" an item that's buried deep within an association structure.

In this case, it starts with a `task_group`. And from that `task_group`, I need to get the `parent_image`'s, which resides at the end of several associations.

Here is how I'm currently handling it:

```
task_group.tasks
  .map(&:submissions).flatten
  .map(&:taggables).flatten
  .map(&:images).flatten
  .map(&:parent_image)
```

Is there a more efficient way of going about this type of query?

Perhaps the query could somehow limit the content the amount of data returned each time? For example, rather than have `&:submissions`, `&:taggables`, `&:images` .map calls return the entire records each time, could I have them pull out only, say, the `:id` attribute, and let the final `&:parent_image` map call return the full record?

Thank you in advance for any guidance or insights!

---

**UPDATE:**  Learning about how to use the `.joins` method as recommended by @Deepak . I'm almost there!

`parent_images = Image.joins(crops: [tags: [:submission [task: :task_group]]])`

This returns an `Image::ActiveRecord_Relation` that I can call `.ids` or `.uniq` on to get an array.

It seems `.joins` directly references field names. Which is well and good, except in this instance, `taggables` that I used in the original `.map` calls is a quick and dirty "catch-all" for several different associations.

```
has_many :tags
has_many :people
has_many :businesses
...
```

```
def taggables
  tags + people + businesses ...
end
```

I wonder, then, is it possible to reference a method as part of `.joins` query (possibly with `.where()`, though I'm not sure how that would it in...)? Or will I need to explicitly state each of the `taggables` associations directly somehow?

Comment: I think using joins is better option so that you make one single query to database. ref: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/joins

Comment: @Deepak Any ideas related to the update I added to the OP? Thanks to your suggestion, I'm allllmost there :)

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve. But, to answer your question yes you can where method to filter the images for corresponding task_group. Also, you can call .to_sql method to understand the sql version of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Deepak's suggestion, I am able to combine .joins with .where in the following manner, in order to get all of the parent_images related to a given task_group:

```
tg = TaskGroup.find(2)
parent_images = Image.joins(crops: [tags: [submission: [task: :task_group]]]).where(task_groups: { id: tg  })
```

Or say I'm to pull all of the images related to a given TaskGroup, one association 'removed' from the parent_images:

```
tg = TaskGroup.find(2)
images = Image.joins(tags: [submission: [task: :task_group]]).where(task_groups: { id: tg  })
```

Now, my understanding of .joins is that the arguments need to relate to fields found in their respective tables. This means that, when using .map, I could call the `taggables` method, but when using .joins, this does not seem to be possible.

So the workaround I'm using at the moment is to call each of the `taggables` models separately, then combine the results.

```
tag_crops = Image.joins(people: [submission: [task: :task_group]]).where(task_groups: { id: tg  })
business_crops = Image.joins(businesses: [submission: [task: :task_group]]).where(task_groups: { id: tg  })
...
```

And then combine each of those together into one giant list

```
crop_image_ids = tag_crops.ids.uniq +
                 person_crops.ids.uniq +
                 business_crops.ids.uniq +
                 ...

crop_image_ids = crop_image_ids.uniq
```